# Yii: Issue in RadioButtonList

Tags: php, yii, radiobuttonlist

Problem in `radioButtonList`. I am having two `radio` buttons as shown below. I am performing `AJAX` action on first radio button.

But when I try click the second radio button, the first one is not getting unchecked and I am not able to check the second one.

```
<?php echo CHtml::radioButtonList( 'ck_Skill','',
    array(4 => 'Professional Skill', 5 => 'Suggestion'), 
    array('separator' => ' ',
    'onChange'=>CHtml::ajax(array('type'=>'POST', 'dataType'=>'json',"url" =>array("search/search"),
    "success"=>"function(response){
         $('#textfield-wrapper').html(response.data);
     }",
))));?>
```

What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this article can help:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/110/styling-radio-buttons/

Or even this one: http://code.dimilow.com/yii-radio-button-list-example-or-how-to-remove-the-line-break-separator/

Things that I notice in your code ([Yii class reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#radioButtonList-detail)):

- Where is the model?
- Where the select name?

Anyway, below an example of this, try take out your javascript code, to make easier figure out the problem:

```
<?php echo CHtml::radioButtonList($model, 'ck_Skill',
    array(4 => 'Professional Skill', 5 => 'Suggestion'), 
    array('separator' => ' ',
    'onChange'=>CHtml::ajax(array('type'=>'POST', 'dataType'=>'json',"url" =>array("search/search"),
    "success"=>"function(response){
         $('#textfield-wrapper').html(response.data);
     }",
))));?>
```